# Is it possible to access the shape of tensorflow tensors without running them?

Tags: tensorflow

I think there is a shape inference mechanism, but I'm not sure how I can access the inferred shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the shape op on the tensor, just call tensor.get_shape().